# Pronunciation vs Spelling of Done

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling, vowel-length

Why is 'Done' pronounced with a short ŏ vowel sound instead of the long ō vowel sound? Rules typically dictate when a word ends with an E, it changes the O to a long vowel sound.  I've tried to find the etymology, but can't really find anything.

Comment: Compare _love_, _glove_, _mother_, _cover_, _Somerset_ - all with sonant consonants following. But I can only think of one other example where the sequence 'one' has the /ʌ/ vowel! Note however that _son_ and _ton_ have that vowel rather than the expected one; and _gone_ and (for some people) _scone_ have a different but also "short" (actually "lax") vowel. Because English spelling.

Comment: Done, gone, cone

Comment: The simplest answer: because English is weird and inconsistent :-)

Answer (score 2):

Two words: vowels shifted.

In general, there are no perfect *rules* in English spelling. As this article notes, there are at least [three ways](https://www.antimoon.com/how/pronunciation-unpredictable.htm) to pronounce words ending in -one: bone, gone, done. Similar pairs or trios can be found for any common spelling scheme in Englishes across the globe.

In exploring the applicability of the "magic " or "silent e" rule, the *Dictionary of the British English Spelling System* (2015) says that the collocation of letters o.e (o, a consonant, and e) generates a long o or /əʊ/ (bone) 95% of the time (p. 453). Combined with similar rules for other vowels, that's a good enough rule for a spelling class. However, two major exceptions occur for this: having a short u or /ʌ/ (done, love) or having the final letter e be pronounced with a long e or /i/ (abalone).

*Done* (and some other o.e words using /ʌ/) is an exception because of changes in vowel pronunciation between Middle English and today. Here is how the Oxford English Dictionary explains it within its etymology of *do, v.*:

> The Old English past participle shows the -n ending of the strong past
>   participle and apparently the same stem vowel as in the present stem
>   (usually as prefixed -dōn : see Forms 7α). The rare Old English past
>   participle form -dēn (only attested in prefixed form: see Forms 7β)
>   apparently shows an i-mutated form of ō (reflecting variation in the
>   participial suffix). [Like *does*], modern standard English done ( Brit. /dʌn/
>   ,  U.S. /dən/ ) *reflects a shortening of the reflex of Middle English
>   long close ō*.

The sound change is rather complex, but the first step is traced through step 2 of this chart modeling the [Great Vowel Shift](http://facweb.furman.edu/~mmenzer/gvs/what.htm):

[image]

From here, the /u/ sound shifted further to /ʌ/ via /ʊ/. In common pronunciation terms, we went

- from the *o* sound in bone  (/o/)
- to the *oo* sound in boon  (/u/)
- to the *oo* sound in foot  (/ʊ/)
- to the *o* sound in done.  (/ʌ/)

And if you're American, we stop the last step at the unaccented vowel /ə/:

- to the unaccented "uh" vowel in done (/ə/)

In other words, we moved where the vowel was pronounced in the mouth over time, just as we did for *thumb* and *dumb*, which had *-ome* or *-oom* forms in Middle English:

[image]

It's hard to say more because [it's hard to explain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift#Causes) why the Great Vowel Shift happened, but that's the track *done* followed.